# Happy Number Function Won't Return True

Tags: python, recursion, return

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kC6YObu61_w

After watching the linked video "7 and Happy Numbers", I decided to write up a bit of code to check whether or not the given number is a happy number.

```
c = []
num = int(input("What number would you like to check? "))
def happyNum(n):
    newNum = 0
    c = []
    a = str(n)
    for b in a:
        c.append(int(b))
    for d in c:
        newNum = newNum + d**2
    if newNum <= 1:
        return True
    elif newNum == 145:
        return False
    elif newNum == 113:
        return False
    elif newNum == 130:
        return False
    else:
        happyNum(newNum)
if happyNum(num) == True:
    print("You've found yourself a happy number!")
elif happyNum(num) == False:
    print("Not a happy number I'm afraid!")
```

I tested it with 7, which I knew from the video is a lucky number, and found that nothing was printed. I did a few tests, and the function works fine. Once it reaches 1, it enters the if statement. The only problem is that it never returns True. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? By the way, incase this might be significant, the function is recursive.

Comment: you are missing a return statement `return happyNum(newNum)` in the `happyNum` function

Comment: Where should that go?

Comment: in your `else` of the `happyNum` function. And BTW, you willget an endless loop in your function if the input is not a happy number.

Comment: I changed the else statement to "else:
        return happyNum(newNum) " and it still isn't returning True

Comment: Is it normal that at any call of `happyNum`, `c` is set to the empty list?

Comment: Yes, c is the list where I store every digit that in n. Given the number 127, c would be [1,2,7].  If I didn't set it empty at each call of happyNum,  previous uses of c would tamper with newer uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is incomplete in its description of happy numbers.  Numbers that are happy will wind up at 1 but they don't say what happens with unhappy numbers.  If they are unhappy, they will eventually cycle through a series of numbers.  So to detect if they are unhappy, you have to keep track of the numbers produced and see if you get any repeats.  (Presumably what you had `c = []` for but didn't use in the end.) This means you need to pass a growing set along in your recursive calls.  The numbers 145, 113 and 130 aren't generally useful and shouldn't be in your code.

Here's a rework that addresses the above issues:

```
def is_happy(number, seen=None):

    if number == 1:  # it's happy
        return True

    if seen is None:
        seen = set()

    if number in seen:  # a cycle, it's unhappy
        return False

    seen.add(number)

    # separate the digits into a list; several ways to do this
    digits = [ord(digit) - ord('0') for digit in str(number)]

    number = 0  # we can reuse number as we got what we needed

    for digit in digits:
        number += digit ** 2

    return is_happy(number, seen)  # this could have also been a loop

number = int(input("What number would you like to check? "))

if is_happy(number):
    print("You've found yourself a happy number!")
else:
    print("Not a happy number I'm afraid!")
```

But, if we find a happy number, then all the numbers we checked in the process of determing that it is happy, are themselves happy.  Ditto for unhappy numbers.  So if we add some caching, using dangerous default values that carry through to subsequent calls:

```
def is_happy(number, seen=None, happy=set([1]), unhappy=set()):

    if seen is None:
        seen = set()

    if number in happy:  # it's happy
        happy.update(seen)  # all seen numbers are happy too
        return True

    if number in unhappy or number in seen:  # a cycle, it's unhappy
        unhappy.update(seen)  # all seen numbers are unhappy too
        return False

    seen.add(number)

    # separate the digits into a list; several ways to do this
    digits = [ord(digit) - ord('0') for digit in str(number)]

    number = 0  # we can reuse number as we got what we needed

    for digit in digits:
        number += digit ** 2

    return is_happy(number, seen)  # this could have also been a loop

for number in range(1, 1000001):
    if is_happy(number):
        print(number, end=" ")
print()
```

We can determine the happiness of numbers up to a million in 1/6 of the time than if we hadn't kept track of previous happy and unhappy numbers!